# resource is not indexed in grails project and sonar

Tags: maven, grails, sonarqube

I want to use sonar to monitor the junit test code coverage for a grails project. firstly I use grails code coverage plugin to generate the coverage.xml and configure sonar.groovy.cobertura.reportPath property, but there is no data in junit part. So I change the sonar.sources in the pom.xml from grails-app to grails-app/controllers,grails-app/services,grails-app/domain. then the junit code coverage appears but the console shows resource is not index.and the issues part in sonar dashboard becomes 0.  How can i solve that? thank you very much.
sonarqube 4.5.1
Groovy sonar plugin 1.0.1
maven 3.2.5
the pom configuration is below:

```
<sonar.language>grvy</sonar.language>
<sonar.dynamicAnalysis>reuseReports</sonar.dynamicAnalysis>
<sonar.surefire.reportsPath>test/reports</sonar.surefire.reportsPath>
<sonar.groovy.cobertura.reportPath>test/reports/cobertura/coverage.xml</sonar.groovy.cobertura.reportPath>
<!--sonar.groovy.codenarc.reportPath>test/CodeNarcReport.xml</sonar.groovy.codenarc.reportPath-->
<sonar.sources>src/groovy,src/java,grails-app/controllers,grails-app/services,grails-app/domain</sonar.sources>
```

BR,
victor

Answer (score 2):

It seems that your problem is related to the following issue: http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONARGROOV-8

Note that the ticket has been resolved and the fix will be part of version 1.1 of the plugin (requires SQ 4.5.2).

As the plugin has not yet been released, you may want to test the snapshot. Please refer to this thread: http://sonarqube.15.x6.nabble.com/VOTE-Groovy-Plugin-version-1-1-td5033128.html

Comment: Hi, michael , thank you very much for your reply. But I cant move SQ from 4.5.1 to 4.5.2. How can modify your source code of 1.0.1 to workaround? for example I add another property named sonar.groovy.sources <sonar.groovy.sources>src/groovy,src/java,grails-app/controllers,grails-app/services,grails-app/domain</sonar.groovy.sources>. then in the groovy plugin, I can reset context value for the source. What do you think? thank you very much

Comment: The issue you are facing come from the fact that source folders are ignored reading coverage reports in version 1.01 of the plugin. 

If you want to fix it on your side, then get the source from https://github.com/m-g-sonar/sonar-groovy/releases/tag/1.0.1 and modify the code of the cobertura report parser to take source folder into account. This commit may guide you https://github.com/SonarCommunity/sonar-groovy/commit/54645780c35f462ba76ee22d8ba53c06361d207b

Comment: Hi, deal michael,  as what you said, I changed the source codes and now I can get the junit test coverage. But the technical Debt and technica Debt Ratio become 0. so which codes are relative with these? thank you very much

Comment: Technical Debt and technical Debt Ratio has nothing to do with code coverage. Your fix should not have had any impact on this calculation. You may have a problem with how issues are calculated.

Comment: Dear Michael,  I just moved the corbenarc part of your lastest codes to my side. change the 1.0.1 pom to 4.5.1 sonar version. I did change some codes in codenarc, but I dont know which codes impact the technical debt. Could you tell me the Technical Debt codes ? they are in codenarc package? thank your for your help

Comment: For the Groovy plugin, technical dept is calculated based on issues extracted from the CodeNarc xml report. It's the CodeNarcSensor class which is responsible of adding issues.

Comment: now I have issues but no techinical debt, it is very strage

Comment: Can you give me the keys of some of the issues you currently have (for instance: org.codenarc.rule.dry.DuplicateListLiteralRule, org.codenarc.rule.basic.ExplicitGarbageCollectionRule or org.codenarc.rule.convention.HashtableIsObsoleteRule)

Comment: org.codenarc.rule.basic.EmptyCatchBlockRule ， org.codenarc.rule.braces.ElseBlockBracesRule. the problem is if I use your original 1.0.1 plugin, it is ok(both issues and technical debt), but If I use my modified version, just issues part is ok and technical debt is 0. I dont know why. wait for your reply.  by the way my skype is zhaobo.qin, if you want, you can add me, maybe it is more convenient to communicate

Comment: Let's summarize your problem:
- You had a zero code coverage with plugin 1.0.1 but, you had issues and technical depth.
- You applied a fix to get coverage from cobertura reports
- You lost technical dept in the process.
Right?
If the calculation of the code coverage may have an impact on the dept, it should not disable its calculation and you probably changed something unwanted. From now on, I won't be able to help you as I don't know exactly what you modified. You may want to make a fork of the project on github to show your changes. I won't use skype.

Comment: I find something. In the original 1.0.1 version, there is a class named CodeNarcRuleRepository which controls the issues and technical debt. in my side, I use sonar 4.5.1, so I delete this class and add CodeNarcRulesDefinition class, then I just have issues and no technical debt. I think that is why